# Record or crop video with custom aspect ratio with AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I want to record a video in a square format, so I insert the preview layer into a square UIView, but when the video is saved to Gallery, it is not square anymore, it has default iPhone aspect ratio (3/4 I guess).

How can I record a video with a custom aspect ratio other than default one? 
Also, if it is not possible, how can I crop it after it is recorded, using `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate`'s method `didFinishRecordingTo`?

Thanks in advance!